# Creating Network Dataset programatically

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, network-analyst, network-dataset

I'm trying to code to create a network dataset using a single line feature class with minimal attributes
I'm looking for a nice tutorial which can guide me through the process.I have already looked at the examples provided by esri (http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000466000000) but they are really complex and specific to the question, its really hard to get the concept from it.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a network dataset programmatically IS a rather advanced process which requires a fairly good understanding of the ArcObjects and network dataset concepts.

There is a chance you miss some of the experience required. To get started with ArcObjects, consider going through the [documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Introduction_to_NET_for_ArcObjects_developers/00010000043s000000/) and get more practice with the [new ArcObjects book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118442547). To learn more about network datasets, read the [ArcGIS Desktop Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004700000007000000).

Esri has also published a toolbox with the source code ([StreetDataProcessing toolbox](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=755f96fcde454ece8f790fecb3e031c7)) that does create a network dataset from the source raw data which you might explore to get a better understanding. Feel free to play with the code and modify it to make it suit your needs.